# ionic 3 alert font-sizing

Tags: sass, ionic2, ionic3

i'm using the ion-select => ion-option as an input for my ionic 3 project. It gives an alert on selection, however the font-size of the alert body is really small and i have tried all sass options to increase its font-size all in vain. I have tried using `.alert-md`,`.alert-tappable`. Is there any way i can increase this font.

[image]

**.scss**

```
.ios, .md {
  page-add-stock {
    /*.alert-md .alert-checkbox-label{

    }*/
    .alert-radio-label {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
  <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="category" formControlName="category" >
    <ion-option>Pesticides</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Seeds</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Herbicides</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Fertilizers</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Farming tools</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Html ion-select that generates the alert, just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot find any Ionic Sass variable related to the labels (I found one for the message, the title and the subtitle of the alert, but not for the labels), so you can always use a css style rule to set the right font-size:

```
.alert-radio-label {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

The default is `font-size: 1.6rem;` for Android, and `font-size: 1.4rem;` for iOS.

**UPDATE**

Please notice that the alert html element is outside the page, so that style rule should be placed in the `app.scss` file.

Comment: still no effect

Comment: Please try by wrapping the style rules from your pages like this `.ios, .md { your-page-name { /* put your styles here...* / } }`

Comment: There must be some rule overriding these styles, I've checked this locally and the style rule does change the font size. Do you have any other style rule related to the alert? Could you please paste the content of the `.scss` file of that page?

Comment: Oh, seems like the alert html element is not inside of the page. Could you please try by setting that rule (`.alert-radio-label { font-size: 3rem; }`) in your `app.scss` file?

Comment: that worked, seems i didn't take into consideration the alert hierachy. Thanks @sebaferreras

Comment: I didn't think about that either, sorry! I've added that to the answer, so it could help other SO users. Glad to hear that it worked :)